# Slow animations in ReactNative's android app

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am using **redux** with **react-native** and on one page I have used **FlatList** and some animations using `Animated.new()`.
Also in he app I am using react-navigation but my app's UI is animating very slow. One reason is that list is in hundreds.
I have tried to enhance FlatList performance by using `getItemLayout` but still app is behaving very slow although same code is working much efficiently on ios.

I have gone through following URL:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html

Can anyone guide me how can I improve performance here?

**EDITED:**

Performance is improved after adding **getItemLayout** and **onEndReachedThreshold** but still drawer icon is unresponsive some times.

```
<FlatList
                    refreshControl={
                        <RefreshControl
                            refreshing={this.props.gameList.get('isFetching')}
                            onRefresh={()=>{
                                this.props.getGameList()
                            }}/>}
                    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.gameListContent}
                    data={gameListData}
                    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
                    renderItem={props=>this.renderItem({...props, isFirst: props.index === 0, isLast: props.index === gameListData.length-1})}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                    initialNumToRender={25}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                />
```

Comment: Have you put your tried animations on the native driver? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html#using-the-native-driver

Comment: If list is small then animation works much much better. fps are reduced 2 or -2

Comment: If you have 500x records, I would load the first 25 into the FlatList, when I scroll to the bottom, load 25 more. Using `onEndReachedThreshold={5}` as you reach the 20th item, it'll load more.

Comment: @Dan I'll try this one.

Comment: @Dan still drawer menu is unresponsive some times. Can you check code attached in updated description?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating **PureComponent** for each list item helped me improved list performance. However some people suggested to use **ListView** instead of **FlatList** but I didn't try that. Follow following URL for more details:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13649

Comment: Is the situation is same with RN v.0.60 and above? I am trying to animate the marginBottom of my list header depending on the FlatList scroll position but animating maxHeight or marginBottom is not suported with native driver. Without native driver iOS still performs well but for Android i can't even say it is slow, it is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of FlatLsit, on initial render pass data to it by slicing 10 to 15, and on **scrollUp** event pass all data to is, because it loads more data as we specify in **setInitilaItemToRender**, because it triggers **onEndReached** event several time.